# Spring WebClient can't read request body before send with ExchangeFilterFunction

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

All the time I used RestTemplate and decided to switch to WebClient.

Before sending a request, I sign request body with a private key and the client checks the request with a public one.

My interceptor:

```
private static class SignatureClientHttpRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    private final PrivateKey privateKey;

    private SignatureClientHttpRequestInterceptor(String privateKeyLocation) {
        this.privateKey = PemUtils.getPrivateKey(Paths.get(privateKeyLocation));
    }

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        if (request.getMethod() == HttpMethod.POST) {
            request.getHeaders().add("X-Signature", Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(PemUtils.signData(privateKey, SignatureAlgorithm.RS256.getJcaName(), body)));
        }
        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
}
```

But at WebClient I did not find such an opportunity in ExchangeFilterFunction.

Is there anyway to do this in WebClient or do I have to manually sign the request body before sending it?

Comment: Hey, man @Peter. Facing similar situation. Where you able to get working? If so kindly share

Comment: @Enoobong Unfortunately, I could not solve it

Answer (score 1):

Signing the body would require it in serialized form, but serialization happens just before sending the data so it needs to be intercepted somehow.

In the case of JSON content, you can create your own Encoder (wrapping the existing `Jackson2JsonEncoder` for example) and passing this as an `ExchangeStrategies` when building the `WebClient`. After the serialized data is intercepted, you can inject the headers. But the Encoder does not have a reference to the `ClientHttpRequest` so you will need to capture this object in an `HttpConnector` and pass it in the `SubscriberContext`.

This blog post explains the process: https://andrew-flower.com/blog/Custom-HMAC-Auth-with-Spring-WebClient#s-post-data-signing

As an example, your `WebClient` creation step might look like below, where `MessageCapturingHttpConnector` is a connector that captures the `ClientHttpRequest` and `BodyCapturingJsonEncoder`

```
Signer signer = new Signer(clientId, secret);
MessageSigningHttpConnector httpConnector = new MessageSigningHttpConnector();
BodyCapturingJsonEncoder bodyCapturingJsonEncoder
    = new BodyCapturingJsonEncoder(signer);

WebClient client
    = WebClient.builder()
               .exchangeFunction(ExchangeFunctions.create(
                       httpConnector,
                       ExchangeStrategies
                              .builder()
                               .codecs(clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer -> {
                                   clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(bodyCapturingJsonEncoder);
                                   clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(new ObjectMapper(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                               })
                               .build()
               ))
               .baseUrl(String.format("%s://%s/%s", environment.getProtocol(), environment.getHost(), environment.getPath()))
               .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
               .build();
```